# DGEMM and DGEMV give different results

Tags: c, blas

I want to implement the following equation in C:

```
C[l,q,m] = A[m,q,k] * B[k,l]
```

where the repeated index k is being summed over.

I implemented this in three ways:

- Naive implementation with loops
- Using the BLAS routine DGEMV (matrix-vector multiplication)
- Using the BLAS routine DGEMM (matrix-matrix multiplication)

This is the minimal not-working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cblas.h>

void main()
{

    const size_t n = 3;
    const size_t n2 = n*n;
    const size_t n3 = n*n*n;

    /* Fill rank 3 tensor with random numbers */
    double a[n3];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n3; i++) {
        a[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    /* Fill matrix with random numbers */
    double b[n2];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        b[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    /* All loops */
    double c_exact[n3];
    memset(c_exact, 0, n3 * sizeof(double));
    for (size_t l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        for (size_t q = 0; q < n; q++) {
            for (size_t m = 0; m < n; m++) {
                for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    c_exact[l*n2+q*n+m] += a[m*n2+q*n+k] * b[k*n+l];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Matrix-vector */
    double c_mv[n3];
    memset(c_mv, 0, n3 * sizeof(double));
    for (size_t m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        for (size_t l = 0; l < n; l++) {
            cblas_dgemv(
                    CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, n, n, 1.0, &a[m*n2],
                    n, &b[l], n, 0.0, &c_mv[l*n2+m], n);
        }
    }

    /* Matrix-matrix */
    double c_mm[n3];
    memset(c_mm, 0, n3 * sizeof(double));
    for (size_t m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        cblas_dgemm(
                CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasTrans, n, n, n, 1.0, b, n,
                &a[m*n2], n, 0.0, &c_mm[m], n2);
    }

    /* Compute difference */
    double diff_mv = 0.0;
    double diff_mm = 0.0;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < n3; idx++) {
        diff_mv += c_mv[idx] - c_exact[idx];
        diff_mm += c_mm[idx] - c_exact[idx];
    }
    printf("Difference matrix-vector: %e\n", diff_mv);
    printf("Difference matrix-matrix: %e\n", diff_mm);
}
```

And this the output:

```
Difference matrix-vector: 0.000000e+00
Difference matrix-matrix: -1.188678e+01
```

i.e. the DGEMV implementation is correct, the DGEMM not - I really don't understand this. I switched around the multiplication (matrix-matrix multiplication is non commutative) and transposed both to get the right order C[l,q,m] instead of C[q,l,m], but I also tried it without switching/transposing and it does not work.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks.

edit: I thought about it a bit and feel like I'm trying to do something that DGEMM doe not support? Namely I try to insert a submatrix into C[:,:,m], which means that both the leading and trailing index are not contiguous in memory. DGEMM allows me to set the parameter LDC, which in this case needs to be n^2, but it does not know that also the second index is non-contiguous with a stride of n (and there is no parameter to tell it?). So why does DGEMM not support a second parameter for the stride of the trailing dimension?

Comment: DGEMM supports enough stride (storage-spacing) parameters to allow for the manipulation of arbitrary rectangular sub-matrices of `A`, `B`, and `C`. That seems sensible enough, but if you need to know more about the design rationale, try contacting one of the original BLAS creators.

Comment: @njuffa Arbitrary sub-matrices? Then I must be missing something. Assuming all dimensions to be of extent N, I can see how i can insert into the submatrix `C[i,:,:]` (set `LDC` to N pass `&C[i*N^2]`), I can see how I can insert into `C[:,i,:] `(set `LDC` to N^2, pass `&C[i*N])`, but I cannot see how I can insert into `C[:,:,i]`  (`LDC` would need to be N^2 and I would need to pass `&C[i]`, but BLAS does not know that the middle index also has a stride of N). What am I missing?

Comment: A term of `N**2` in the indexing computation for a *rectangular* sub-matrix looks wrong to me, shouldn't that be something like `LDC*N`? Also, there is no such thing as *inserting* a sub-matrix with `GEMM`, as the (scaled) product is *added* to `C`. Assuming that what you are trying to achieve can be done with `GEMM` (I am not sure about that), you might try drawing the matrices and annotating the drawing with the `GEMM` parameters. Keep in mind that column-major storage order is being used to store the matrices.

Comment: My submatrices are square though (all extends are N), not rectangular. Otherwise it wouldn't be `N**2` but `N*M` or similar. My parameter alpha is 1.0 and beta is 0.0, which is equivalent to inserting into `C`. I use cblas_dgemm with CblasRowMajor as first paramter, which I would assume is consistent with my row major storage.
What do you mean with "drawing the matrices"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the scale factor on `C`. I find it useful to always distinguish between the dimensions of the sub-matrix ('N', ...) and the dimensions of the full matrix ('LDC', ...), even if they happen to coincide for a particular case. By "drawing" I meant taking a pencil and a sheet of paper to draw the layout of the 2D matrices as part of the process of reasoning about a BLAS operation. That is what I have done in the past when I managed to confuse myself as to the inner workings of some BLAS function with its numerous parameters, especially transpose modes.

Comment: If you want arbitrary strides along any dimension you can have a look at [BLIS](https://github.com/flame/blis).